# scikit learn: How to include others features after performed fit and transform of TFIDFVectorizer?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-mining, feature-extraction

Just a brief idea of my situation:
I have 4 columns of input: **id**, **text**, **category**, **label**.

I used **TFIDFVectorizer** on the **text** which gives me a list of instances with word tokens of TFIDF score.

Now I'd like to include the **category** (no need to pass TFIDF) as another feature in the data outputed by the vectorizer.

Also note that prior to the vectorization, the data have passed **train_test_split**.

How could I achieve this?

Initial code:

```
#initialization
import pandas as pd
path = 'data\data.csv'
rappler= pd.read_csv(path)
X = rappler.text
y = rappler.label
#rappler.category - contains category for each instance

#split train test data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)

#feature extraction
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_dtm = vect.fit_transform(X_train)
#after or even prior to perform fit_transform, how can I properly add category as a feature?
X_test_dtm = vect.transform(X_test)

#actual classfication
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
nb = MultinomialNB()
nb.fit(X_train_dtm, y_train)
y_pred_class = nb.predict(X_test_dtm)

#display result
from sklearn import metrics
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred_class))
```

Comment: What is the type of your category ? a string ? If it's a string you can encode the feature

Comment: @MMF Yes, it's a string. But if integer is required, I can make it happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing your train test split after feature extraction.

Once you have the TF-IDF feature lists just add the other feature for each sample.

You will have to encode the category feature, a good choice would be [sklearn's LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html). Then you should have two sets of numpy arrays that can be joined.

Here is a toy example:

```
X_tfidf = np.array([[0.1, 0.4, 0.2], [0.5, 0.4, 0.6]])
X_category = np.array([[1], [2]])
X = np.concatenate((X_tfidf, X_category), axis=1)
```

At this point you would continue as you were, starting with the train test split.

Comment: Hi @AlexG, the reason I do train test split first is to prevent the model to be overfitted by the features (from test data).

Comment: You should still do train test split before training the model ... but after feature engineering.

Answer (score 0):

> You should use [FeatureUnions - as explained in the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html#featureunion-composite-feature-spaces)
>
> > FeatureUnions combines several transformer objects into a new
> >     transformer that combines their output. A FeatureUnion takes a list of
> >     transformer objects. During fitting, each of these is fit to the data
> >     independently. For transforming data, the transformers are applied in
> >     parallel, and the sample vectors they output are concatenated
> >     end-to-end into larger vectors.

Another good example on how to use FeatureUnions can be found here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html

Just concatenating different matrices like @AlexG suggests is probably an easier option but FeatureUnions is the scikit-learn way to do these things.